# Airflow Backfilling DAG

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Very simple question - so much headache

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dag_id',
    start_date=datetime(2018, 8, 8),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5)
)

BashOperator(
    task_id="xyz",
    bash_command='python3 abc.py',
    dag=dag,
)
```

I set it to run every five mins and the start date is `datetime(2018, 8, 8)`
it starts to backfill since `2018-10-11 20:50`

like waaaat

My time difference with UTC is 4 hours; and it runs jobs post process

thus @ `~15:16` today it produces a log with `19:10:53` timestamp on it. I guess its fine, kind of, but why did backfill start @ `2018-10-11 20:50`?

Also, it does not seem to recognize chron expressions. No job triggers at all... ex: its "15:42" here, I set it to run @ `19 45 * * *` and nothing happens (`start_date` is also in the past).

Am I doing something wrong?